# JavaFX TextField focusProperty lost on touchScrollEvent

Tags: java, scroll, javafx, touch, focus

I am showing a Keyboard if the user clicks into a my extended `TextField` with the code shown below. When scrolling with a mouse you don't loose the focus to the `TextField`, but when scrolling by touch the focus is lost - and keyboard dispears of course. Is there a way to get the same behavior on touchScroll as on mouseScroll? I don't want the keyboard to disapear if the user is scrolling with touch!

```
focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, final Boolean oldValue,
                final Boolean newValue) {

                KeyboardUtils.INSTANCE.setVisible(newValue);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty basic sir, when you are scrolling with a Touchscroll you definitely Touch a scrollable `Pane` area, and that `Pane` `requestFocus()`by the touch, so your `TextField` will loose its focus.

so to solve it you send focus back to your `TextField` if you detect a touch either by using the Scrolling listener of that Pane or Node or go for `setOnTouchStationary()` or `setOnTouchReleased()`, to help tweak the visibility of your keyboard instead of lying on focus of your `TextField`.

**EDIT**

Try this

```
Node lastFocusedNode =null; // lastly known node to have focus
//now every node or child in your ScrollPane or Scrollable parent 
//that you care about will have a focusable listener-including
// your textfield
textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
@Override
public void changed(
        ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                if(!newValue){//if they loose focus
                    lastFocusedNode = textField;
                    //if they loose focus attach them to lastFocusedNode
                }
            }
        });
 //the above saves you iterations
```

then when your ScrollPane/scrollable Node  Receives focus you set them to the `lastFocusedNode` since its just going to allow scrolling.

```
sp.focusedProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {               
            @Override
            public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
                if (lastFocusedNode != null) {
                    lastFocusedNode.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        });
```

the above assumes your ScrollPane will just not do anything consuming aside from scrolling..

if you ScrollPane/scrollable parent is not going with that assumption then
you go with this approach-detect when the user scrolls after touching your content area of your Scrollable Node-this works only if user attempts to scroll after touching.

```
//approach loaded
final InvalidationListener lis = new InvalidationListener() {               
@Override
public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
    //here it is changing
    if(sp.isFocused())
        lastFocusedNode.requestFocus();//take the focus away
    }
};
```

using the above invalidation listener you set it on the hvalueProperty() and vvalueProperty() or your ScrollPane - *which Scrollable parent are you using?*

```
sp.hvalueProperty().addListener(lis);
sp.vvalueProperty().addListener(lis);
```

then you are done. any of the above solution will cause *No problemo*

EDIT 2

from what i know `TouchEvent` is for Touch enabled computers, so maybe go with `MouseEvent` and you can detect `Pane.setOnMousePressed();` etc etcc

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so for every TouchEvent I need to iterate through all children of the Pane to get the Node which is/was focused? (Is this still possible because of the TouchEvent requesting Focus? And on release I requestFocus then? But isn't that really unperformant??

Comment: would you please comment?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really helpful